# Filter criteria not working on new field because data table is not storing data

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a view based on a content type. I added a new boolean field `Premium` to the content type that I wanted to add to the view as filter criteria. However when I added it I got no results in my view, no matter whether I set its filter value to '1' or '0'.

After doing some investigation, I queried the tables and found that `field_data_field_premium` had no values, while `field_revision_field_premium` was storing values. I tested checking and unchecking the `Premium` checkbox on various nodes. The state of the checkbox was preserved on the node, and I confirmed that data was being stored in the revision table, and still there were no rows in the data table. After checking and unchecking the box and saving several times on a single node, the data only stays in the revision table and rows are never inserted in the data table.

This causes my view not to work, because the query that views creates does a join on the data table, not the revision table. Since there are no rows in the data table, the query returns no rows overall since there is nothing to join to.

Thinking that the field was somehow broken, I deleted it and re-created it, but I am still getting the same behavior of data only being stored in the revision table. For further testing, I created another stock Drupal site, with a content type that has a boolean field. My test site is storing data in both the data and revision table.

What is going on? Is the field screwed up somehow on this site? The content type I'm adding this field to is in a feature -- could that be the source of the problem?

*Edit* I just exported and reverted the feature with my field added, and I still get the same behavior of values, either 1 or 0, only being stored in the field's revision table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. We have the workbench module installed on this site for multi-stage moderation, and the node I was editing was not the published version of the draft :þ